# Get a testable attribute for RedirectToAction method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm trying to test my controller, which is used for registration of new users.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(ClientViewModel clientViewModel)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var client = new Client
            {
                //filling object from clientViewModel
            };

            var license = new License
            {
                //filling object from clientViewModel
            };

            if (AccountFacade.AddClientLicense(client, license))
            {
                var licenseId = AccountFacade.GetLicenseIdForUsername(Applications.UBetPro, clientViewModel.UserName);

                if (licenseId.HasValue)
                {
                    AccountFacade.AddAccount(licenseId.Value);
                    return RedirectToAction("RegisterSuccess");
                }
            }

        }

        return View(clientViewModel);
    }
```

This is not the whole code but I think it's the only part relevant for the testing. The methods for adding and validation are called from a facade in the business logic, which is mocked in the unit tests along with all of its methods.
The controller is supposed to redirect the user to the form displayed when the registration is successful, and that's the thing I'm trying to test. This is my unit test:

```
    public void Register_WithUniqueUsernameAndEmail_ReturnsRegistrationSuccessful()
    {
        // Arrange:
        var mock = new Mock<IAccountFacade>();
        mock.Setup(/*mocking methods*/);
        var controller = new AccountController(mock.Object);

        var context = new ControllerContext();

        var fakeClientViewModel = new ClientViewModel
                                  {
                                      FirstName = "test",
                                      ...
                                      ...
                                   };

        // Act:
        var result = controller.Register(fakeClientViewModel);
        // how do I get the name of result or something similar?

        // Assert: ???

    }
```

I'm using Moq and Structure Map for the unit testing. The method setups work fine, the only problem is that I can't access something specific for the result field with which I would be able to recognize it and use it in the Assert part. If the model used View("RegisterSuccess") I guess there wouldn't be any problem, but from what I was able to see the RedirectToAction is not that easily accessible. If there's a solution different than the one I'm trying to use I would be happy to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Register(fakeClientViewModel);
Assert.AreEqual("RegisterSuccess", result.RouteValues["action"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your result as an ActionResult or a RedirectResult depending on which part of the code you're testing

```
var result = controller.Register(fakeClientViewModel) as ActionResult;
```

Once you've done this, you can check the view name, model data etc

Comment: Tried it, returns null for the result object.